# xchat: connecting to one account from two clients

Tags: irc, messaging, xchat, jabber

I am using `xchat` IRC client in Debian. I have two computers, one in my office and another at home. I would like to be connected to my IRC server from both computers using the same account.

People who send messages to me and receive messages from me should not see any difference, and should not even need to know whether I am at home or in the office.

By that I mean, any messages send to my account should appear on both computers. Also, any messages I send, should be visible as sent on both computers (so that both clients have complete history of communication).

From what I could find, there exists such functionality in some jabber implementations (Prosody) and is called mod_carbons.

Does `xchat` client, or the IRC protocol have this functionality?

How would I set this up ?

Comment: Would be solution with something like a proxy in-between be acceptable?

Comment: @phk - I don't know. How would that work ?

Comment: Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_(software), did not use such software myself for a long time though.